# How to allow Netbeans have access on my desktop documents to open project on MAC

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

When I tried to open project which i saved on my desktop, It asked me a question "allow netbeans to access documents on your desktop?" and I accidentally pressed NO. Now I couldn't open project that was saved on my desktop. Anyone know how can I fix this? How can change it to allow netbeans to access my files on my desktop? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue simply start Netbean from the terminal.

```
/Applications/NetBeans/Apache\ NetBeans\ 12.0.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/bin/netbeans
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65582339/10409672

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to MAC and after spending a lot of time here on this issue, I figured out that you need to go to the System preferences and then further move to security.[click to allow after entering your password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F74R.png)