# MacOS Big Sur + Netbeans : cannot open/create projects

Tags: netbeans, macos-big-sur

After MacOS upgrade to Big Sur and having made changes to 'netbeans_jdkhome' into the netbeans.conf file, ***the application is opened and running but it is NOT possible to open one of my projects*** because the box with my project files under "Documents" shows empty content (and of course my files are present there).

Nor is it possible to create a new project, heea some log messages:

```
cd /Users/bparis/Documents/Netbeans; JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home "/Applications/NetBeans/Apache ....
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
pwd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
pwd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted
Scanning for projects...
```

Same issue with Apache NetBeans 11.2 and 12.2.

So I suppose Netbeans is not allowed to access files on disk.
I went into my "System > Preferences > Security and Privacy" to try to change that behavior but Netbeans is not being listed and I can't add it" (+ button non activated).
I can gives Netbeans the permission "Full access" to disk but that does no change.

Thanks for any help,
Bernard

Answer (score 3):

Issue reported to apache devs.

Workaround : start Netbeans from a terminal window:

> "/Applications/NetBeans/Apache NetBeans 11.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/netbeans/bin/netbeans"

Comment: I also dragged 'java' from JDK 15  to 'All Disk Access' - no change.